# Looping through Facebook JSON object

Tags: php, json

I am currently getting the output I desire, although It seems that the only way I can get this to work is with these nasty nested foreach loops.  I know that there must be a better way to loop this this JSON object.

```
$json = 'https://graph.facebook.com/218894654822767_609825405729688?fields=id,likes&key=value&access_token=245675758812857%7Ca2b43c96b8f2db07561ac8f6054b2632';

$fbObject = file_get_contents($json);

$array = json_decode($fbObject, true);

$count = 0;
if(is_array($array))
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $object) {
    if(is_array($object))
    {
      foreach ($object as $likes){
        if(is_array($likes))
        {
          foreach ( $likes as $data ){
            if(is_array($data))
            {
             foreach ( $data as $id ){
              if (is_numeric($id))
                {
                  echo "$id".'<br />';
                } 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

?>

Comment: Can you post the json data

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying:

```
$json_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/218894654822767_609825405729688?fields=id,likes&key=value&access_token=245675758812857%7Ca2b43c96b8f2db07561ac8f6054b2632';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_url));
$user_ids = array();

foreach ($json->likes->data as $user) {
    $user_ids[] = $user->id;
}

print implode('<br />', $user_ids);
```

Simplifying even more:

```
$json_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/218894654822767_609825405729688?fields=id,likes&key=value&access_token=245675758812857%7Ca2b43c96b8f2db07561ac8f6054b2632';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_url));

print implode('<br />', array_map(function ($user) {
        return $user->id;
    }, (array) $json->likes->data));
```

That's all! :)